# Custom URL Formation in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, custom-url

I have a website about song lyrics on WordPress. Format of title for each lyric is "Song Name". Therefore, when I add a new lyric to the site, URL of the page is automatically formed like;

```
//example.com/lyrics/song-name
```

All lyrics has a parameter for artist name called "artist_name". What I want is;

When I add a new lyric to the site with title "Song Name", I want an automatically formed URL with format;

```
//example.com/lyrics/artist-name-song-name
```

Is it possible to achieve an URL with this format?

Otherwise, I need to edit all URL's manually and add artist name to the beginning of the URL by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the artist name in a [Custom Field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), and then use [some plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/) to execute PHP in the post. From there, you can [check the value](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/checking-if-value-is-set-for-a-custom-field) of the custom field for the current post id, and if it is set, change the permalink ('post-name') field using [wp_update_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

Hope this helps, and feel free to ask if you have any further questions about the process.